# Pointing config file's values to different DB Server (with Port) - Correct Syntax?? .NET

Tags: .net, database, configuration, connection, connection-string

So I am moving a database to a different DB server. My new DB server is split into 3 instances (so that my monitoring tools can separate the 3 DBs as different software services by Port number.

The application I am using is MSPetShop! It;s built on the .NET framework, and in order to change the database connection you open a file called 'Web.config'. The following is what my database connection was setup as before (when working on old DB server):

```
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
     <add key="ConnString1" value="server=192.168.35.10; user id=petshop;password=password;database=MSPetShop" />
    </appSettings>
```

I need to change the IP address of this DB server to my new one (which I know is simple), however I need to add the port of which one of my instances sits on. I thought it would look something like this:

```
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
     <add key="ConnString1" value="server=192.168.35.10:1435; user id=petshop;password=password;database=MSPetShop" />
    </appSettings>
```

However no DB connection can be established and the app is not working. Is there a different way this should be written?

Answer (score 1):

**You might have to enable TCP/IP for that instance:**, *also .NET config files when connecting  to SQL server via ADO.NET (SqlClient) do not need the IP:port format, they will recognize named instances.*

Open the Start menu, point to All Programs, point to Microsoft SQL Server 2005 or Microsoft SQL Server 2008, point to Configuration Tools, and then click SQL Server Configuration Manager.

In the tree pane, click SQL Server 2005 Services or SQL Server 2008 Services.

In the results pane, verify that, under the State column, Running appears next to the name of each service.

If Stopped appears, right-click the name of the service, and click Start.

In the tree pane, click SQL Server 2005 Network Configuration or SQL Server 2008 Network Configuration to expand it, and then click Protocols for MSSQLServer/MyInstanceName.

If you specified the default instance during installation, the instance name will be MSSQLSERVER.

In the results pane, verify that, under the Status column, Enabled appears next to the name of the TCP/IP protocol.

If Disabled appears, right-click TCP/IP, and then click Enable.

In the tree pane, click SQL Native Client Configuration to expand it, and then click Client Protocols.

In the results pane, verify that, under the Status column, Enabled appears next to the name of the TCP/IP protocol.

If Disabled appears, right-click TCP/IP, and then click Enable.

In the tree pane, click SQL Server 2005 Services or SQL Server 2008 Services.

In the results pane, right-click SQL Server (MSSQLServer/MyInstanceName), and then click Restart.

Comment: @kd7 I performed all of these pre-reqs beforehand. TCP/IP is enabled on all of my instances and I have restarted services multiple times. I checked the windows event viewer and the error I am getting is; "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid conntion." I have removed the port reference in the config file alo (so now its just the IP of the server, still no difference though!

Comment: You're connecting to the same ip, have you tried replacing the IP with the named instance i.e. MyServer/Instance in the config file.

Comment: @kd7 apologies the error message now (since removing the port) has changed to "Login failed for user 'petshop'" Is this to do with the username and password or associated user for the database?

Comment: Yes, check that the user "petshop" has appropriate rights on the database on the other server.

Comment: @kd7 Yes, only thing is when I am connecting to Management Studio to my named instance, I use: '\\. \pip\MSSQL$PETHSOP\sql\query' I dont seem to have anywhere a reference to the layout you have provided: 'MyServer/Instance'. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @kd7 yes user does have rights - exactly same setup as "petshop" on old DB server - i.e role of db_owner for petshop DB :(

Comment: So you're using named pipes for connection? Take a look at this then: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/265808

Comment: @kd7 I can connect via namedpipes and also the 'MyServer/Instance' syntax... ever log i check says that 'petshop' login failed - i have made 'petshop' db_owner of the required databases... running out of ideas!!

Comment: @kd7 doesn't work still if i use 'MyServer/Instance' in the config file??? So frustrating :)